# String variable does not change in switch statement. JAVA

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

I'm trying to change a string variable in a switch statement like so:

```
ArrayList<String> listOfWeightLocations = new ArrayList<String>();
String weight;
ArrayList.add(weight);


Switch (num) {
    case 1:
        weight = "This";
        break;
    case 2:
        weight = "Other.";
        break;
    default:
        weight = "Another Either."
        break;
}

System.out.println(String.valueOf(listOfWeightLocations.get(0));
```

But it never changes the values. It stays as null.

Comment: If you mean the object you added to the `ArrayList`, that won't change. The variable `currentState` will, it will contain whatever you assign to it in the `switch` statement.

Comment: why will the object added to the ArrayList not change,

Comment: Because Java is pass-by-value.

Comment: But i thought ArrayList holds object reference not values

Comment: What do you think an object reference is?

Comment: a reference to that variable weight, so when i change weight the reference to it changes to.

Comment: The duplicate explains that that is not the case. Please refresh your page. You'll be able to see the link to it.